# strptime in R returning NA

Tags: r

I have a variable in my dataset called timestamp which is of the form.
mydata$timestamp

`2013-08-01 12:00:00 
2013-08-01 12:00:00 
2013-08-01 12:00:00`

I want to modify these and change them to only dd-mm-yy format
 `dates<-strptime(mydata$timestamp, format="%d:%m:%y")`
 printing dates is resulting in only NA's.  Not sure why.

Could anyone help, please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want `dd-mm-yy` format, you need `format(mydata$timestamp, "%d-%m-%y")`. For example:

```
x <- strptime(c("2006-01-08 10:07:52", "2006-08-07 19:33:02"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "EST5EDT")
[1] "2006-01-08 10:07:52 EST" "2006-08-07 19:33:02 EDT"

format(x, "%d-%m-%y")
[1] "08-01-06" "07-08-06"
```

Answer (score 9):

Pascal's answer is correct, but I'm going to add to it because with all due respect to him I think you need to be aware of the mistakes you are making so you won't make them in the future.

In some programming languages there are internal dates that have associated formats and you can change that format without changing the internal representation of the date.  That is probably why you phrased the question as you did, but that is not the way R works.   In R you can either have dates represented as a string or as an actual date class that R understands, like `Date` or `POSIXlt`.  Classes that R understands don't have any specific output format associated with them.

Your input data appears to be a string representation of a date.  It appears that you want it in a different string representation.   `strptime()` will change from a string to `POSIXlt` but this data type isn't formatted one way or the other. If you want to turn it back into a string, you need to use a different command.  In Pascal's example, that function is `format()`.

Ok, so you want to use `strptime()` to turn it into an R date and then use `format()` to turn it back into a string.  Fine, but you have to have the arguments right.  The second argument to `strptime()` is a set of characters that informs the function of what the current format is.  Your argument `"%d:%m:%y"` is not remotely similar to what your data is.  That's why are getting `NA`.  As Pascal points out, the correct format is `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`.  Check the help file for `strptime()` to see what the symbols in the formatting strings mean.

Personally I avoid all that local time stuff that `strptime()` does and just use R's basic `Date()` class.  My solution would be

```
dates <- format(as.Date(mydata$timestamp,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),format="%d-%m-%y")
```

Notice that that `format` argument in `as.Date()` informs the function of what the incoming data format is and the `format` argument in `format()` tells it what you want the outgoing format to be.